# How to change font size for all text in a ggplot object relative to current value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

When creating plots using ggplot2, I often encounter the following:

I have twitched all the text using `element_text(size=<value>)`, so it looks good in my report, but to use it in another context, I need to update the size of all text (make it bigger or smaller), to keep the plot readable.

Is there a way to update font size for all text elements, without having to explicitly specifying the elements, **i.e. not**

```
theme_update(
       axis.text=element_text(size=12),
       axis.title=element_text(size=14),
       ...
)
```

### Reprex

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris) +
  aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)+
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle(
    "All text",
    "should be 50% larger"
  ) +
  theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ggplot objects are displayed through grid graphics, and grid graphics inherit the parent viewport's cex setting as a multiplier,

```
print(p, vp=grid::viewport(gp=grid::gpar(cex=2)))
```

or (to only affect the theme elements, but won't affect e.g. geom_text layers),

```
p + theme(text=element_text(size=24))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the code in your answer? I can see that `cex` get's the job done, but using `print` with a `vp` argument seems a bit arcane, at least to me.

Comment: the second approach does also not work, if font sizes for the individual elements were previously specified by adding a theme to the plot.